# is there any way to manipulate the background image of a button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

i need to give the size of the background image, because the icon image (32x32) that i am adding as background image to my buttons, are to big for the buttons and it looks bad, the XAML code is this:

```
<Window x:Class="apple.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"> 
        <Grid>
        <Image Source="C:\Users\Fernando\Desktop\Eye-Mouse\apple\apple\img0.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <UniformGrid Name="gridx" Rows="6">
            </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And to the uniformGrid i am adding the buttons, like this:

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
FileToImageIconConverter some = new FileToImageIconConverter(link[n]);
ImageSource imgSource = some.Icon;
ib.ImageSource = imgSource;
newBtn.Background = ib;
gridx.Children.Add(newBtn);
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you give some clarification on what "looks bad" means?  Also, can you add a trimmed screenshot to your question, and give a bit more clarification of what exactly you'd like it to look like instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use Xaml & Databinding to fill the uniform grid. This way, you can style the button in Expression Blend however you like.

```
<Window x:Class="apple.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"> 
        <Grid>
        <Image Source="C:\Users\Fernando\Desktop\Eye-Mouse\apple\apple\img0.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <!-- YourLinkList is the list that provides the link[n] in your example -->
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourLinkList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="6"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush>
                                <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                                    <!-- {Binding .} means that the UriSource is bound to the item in the link list -->
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding .}" DecodePixelWidth="32" DecodePixelHeight="32"/>
                                </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                            </ImageBrush>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You could also try to set the image as the content of the button instead of using it as the background. Maybe that will look better.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i am searching about how to do the link[n] binding Path but i dont get it, can you teach me plz?

Comment: @FernandoSantiago well, i suppose you store the links in a array or list (sth. that implements `IEnumerable<>`). You just need to set the `ItemsSource` of the ItemsControl to that list. The `DataContext` of the n-th item of the ItemsControl then is the n-th item in your list.